# How can I compile a Java class stored in a string, or using it's path with a given input?

Tags: java, file, compilation

I'm trying to make my own pretty print for java files, similar to JDoodle. How can I compile a java class, given either it's location as a string, or its content as a string, as well as do it given a text file for std inputs, all the while recording the output as a seperate string. Sorry if this seems troublesome. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: I do know about the `java.tools.ToolProvider` and `Tool`, but even if it is the solution, I don't know what to do with it, as the documentation is too confusing for me, or too sparse.

Comment: You could run a javac process using ProcessBuilder or Runtime.Exec.

Comment: How is "java.tools.ToolProvider" confusing? There is a static method called "getSystemJavaCompiler" which returns a JavaCompiler type which has methods for compiling. I don't mean that in a derogatory way I just want to know what was confusing so I don't write the same type of documentation.

Comment: @BaileyKocin, is it possible to use it given a text file containing std inputs? If so is there a proper tutorial for it? Sorry..

Comment: You want to read a text file full of java file paths\names to compile and then compile them?

Comment: Why would a pretty-print program compile the code?  Doesn’t a pretty printer format source code?

Comment: @BaileyKocin, ah yeah I'm sorry for that I understand the concern about my understanding, but what I actually meant is that I don't see any proper example with the `compiler.run()` method and its arguments. Also, no the file contains the inputs the program which I want to run receives (i.e.the Scanner values). Not the files to compile. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @VGR, well I realized that's not what a pretty printer is normally. But what JDoodle does is just print the webpage, after I run the code. So yeah, in my case I just need the output, so I need to compile it.

Comment: The documentation has all of the answers.  [The ToolProvider javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html#getSystemJavaCompiler%28%29) shows that the getSystemJavaCompiler method’s return type is JavaCompiler.  If you click that link, you get the [javadoc for JavaCompiler](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html).  Search that page for the first occurrence of `StandardJavaFileManager` and you will see a short but complete example of how to use ToolProvider to compile classes.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got an answer. I used Eclipse's compiler(cause I dont have JDK in my school laptop) to compile and used processbuilder to run the produced .class file, redirected the output using redirectOutput to a file which I read to get the output. Thanks- Here is the code.

```java
/*PRETTYPRINT*/
/*
 * Code to HTML
 * Uses highlightjs in order to create a html form for your code, you can also give inputs and outputs
 * */

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class PrettyPrint {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        String javaFile = readFile(args[0]);
        String commandLine = readFile(args[1]);
        String output = readFile(args[2]);
        String html = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
                +"<html>\n"
                +"<head>"
                +"<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"highlightjs/styles/a11y-dark.css\" media= \"all\">\r\n"
                +"<script src=\"highlightjs/highlight.pack.js\"></script>\r\n"
                +"<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>"
                +"<script src=\"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js\" integrity=\"sha384-NaWTHo/8YCBYJ59830LTz/P4aQZK1sS0SneOgAvhsIl3zBu8r9RevNg5lHCHAuQ/\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\"></script>\r\n"
                +"<script src=\"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/html2canvas@1.0.0-rc.5/dist/html2canvas.min.js\"></script>"
                +"<meta charset=\"utf-8\">"
                +"<style>code{overflow-x: visible;}body{background-color:#888888;color:#444444;}h1{text-align:center;color:#444444;}</style>"
                +"</head>"
                +"<body style=\"font-family: 'Consolas';\">\n"
                +"<h1 style=\"text-align: center\">Java Code</h1>"
                +"<pre><code class=\"java\" style=\"overflow-x:visible\">"
                +toHTML(javaFile)
                +"</code></pre>"
                +"<br>\n"
                +"<h1>Inputs</h1>"
                +"<pre><code class = \"nohighlight hljs\" style=\"overflow-x:visible\">"
                +toHTML(commandLine)
                +"</code></pre>"
                +"<br>\n"
                +"<h1>Output</h1>"
                +"<pre><code class = \"nohighlight hljs\" style=\"overflow-x:visible\">"
                +toHTML(output)
                +"</code></pre>"
                +"</body>\n"
                +"<script>"
                +"console.log(document.body.innerHTML);"
                //+String.format("function print(){const filename='%s';html2canvas(document.body).then(canvas=>{let pdf = new jsPDF('p','mm', 'a4');pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'PNG', 0, 0, 1000, 1000);pdf.save(filename);});}print();",args[3].substring(args[3].lastIndexOf('/')+1, args[3].length()-4)+"pdf")
                + "</script>"
                +"</html>\n";
        //System.out.println(html);
        try {
            File file = new File("output.html");
            PrintWriter fileWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
            fileWriter.print(html);
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public static String toHTML(String str) {
        String html = str;
        html = html.replace("&","&amp;");
        html = html.replace("\"", "&quot;");
        html = html.replace("\'", "&apos;");
        html = html.replace("<", "&lt;");
        html = html.replace(">", "&gt;");
        //html = html.replace("\n", "<br>");
        html = html.replace("\t", "&emsp;&emsp;");
        html+= "<br>";

        return html;
    }
    public static String readFile(String filePath)
    {
        String content = "";
        try
        {
            content = new String ( Files.readAllBytes( Paths.get(filePath) ) );
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content;

    }
}
```

```java
/**PROCESSBUILDEREXAMPLE**/

import java.io.*;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.CompilationProgress;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.batch.BatchCompiler;

public class ProcessBuilderExample {
    private static String JAVA_FILE_LOCATION;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        JAVA_FILE_LOCATION = args[0];
        CompilationProgress progress = null;
        BatchCompiler.compile(String.format("-classpath rt.jar %s",args[0]), new PrintWriter(System.out), new PrintWriter(System.err), progress);

        Process process = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-cp",
                JAVA_FILE_LOCATION.substring(0,JAVA_FILE_LOCATION.lastIndexOf("\\")),
                JAVA_FILE_LOCATION.substring(JAVA_FILE_LOCATION.lastIndexOf("\\")+1,JAVA_FILE_LOCATION.length()-5))
                .redirectInput(new File(args[1]))
                .redirectOutput(new File(args[2])).start();
        try {
            process.waitFor();
            PrettyPrint.main(args);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Keep these 2 in the same folder and run processbuilderexample with 3 arguments. The code's loc, the input file's loc, and the output file to write to.